# Is there a way to have a textbox value show up in another textbox when a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have implemented a trackbar that adjusts a textbox value accordingly with the slider as shown with the code below.

```
private void trackBar_Temp_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Oven_Temp.Text = trackBar_Temp.Value.ToString();
```

I am trying to have the value displayed in the `oven_temp` textbox appear within another textbox called `feedback`, when a button is clicked using this code.

```
private void Oven_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Oven_Temp.Text = Feeback.Text;
```

No errors seem to be appearing however no output appears within the feedback textbox.

Anyone able to help a student out for a coursework who has done a limited amount of coding before? :)

Answer (score 1):

You set `Oven_Temp.Text` to the value of `Feeback.Text`. According to your text, you however wanted to set `Feeback.Text` to the value of `Oven_Temp.Text`. So you got the Assignment flipped.

Try `Feeback.Text = Oven_Temp.Text;`

The other common mistake is that the Event is not actually registered with the Button. You can put a simple Message Box in to test if the event even fires. That is usually one of the first things I check with Events.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Flipping the assignment did not seem to work and neither did the message box . How do I register the event with the button?

Comment: @RAG If you are using the designer, usually you create a event by Double-Clicking on the Button. It will setup and register a empty event for you. | Alternatively, select the button in the designer and look for the "Event" part of the properties. FInd the on Click event and you should be able to select this function. | There is a 3rd code behind way, but better you work with the designer for now.

Comment: Great thank you works perfectly now! Unsure as to why it did not register an event as I always use the double click method. Just one more quick question if possible. If you want  to have the same text in front or after the value when using the button event i.e. "The Value of"  200  "shows such and such"  how would I go about this?

Comment: @RAG I can not parse the question. Now your are talking about having text visually in front of text? Or do you mean append Text in front of `Oven_Temp.Text`, before assigning it to Feedback? If so, string concatenation. However if you do any form of toutorial or have any form of classes, that should come next.